# Is there a way to display whitespace when formatting code?

Tags: feature-request, support, markdown, code-formatting

I'd like to display whitespace characters when writing a question involving a block of text to be parsed. Is there a way to do this?

For example, in Eclipse one can show whitespaces as an Interpunct `·` or whatever this is called: `˚`

> [image]

Comment: Well, not possible with SE editor,  but would be a nice feature.

Comment: It could also be an [Ordinal Indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) or a [Diacritic Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)). They all look very similar and I'm not sure which in particular Eclipse uses.

Comment: it's totally dependent on `SDK` you are using.. There are too much shortcuts to this in different different SDK's. Which SDK you are using